# Linear Model feature selection - AIC vs ANOVA vs t test

Tags: anova, multiple-regression, t-test, aic

Suppose I have a multi regression model, dummy variables and interactions included. How am I suppose to filter through them all in order to choose the best model?

I KNOW this question was asked on various online forums, but so far none could bring an explanation a human being can understand. Moreover, I did several statistics and regression courses at university, and even they can't sum it up into a usable format.

Three tools are in my knowledge:

1. Use R's `summary()` on the model and remove the insignificant variables in the t-test. (However, I know that there may be hidden relations between them, thus removing may not be the best solution)
2. Use AIC's `step()` and include only those chosen variables.
3. Build two models and compare them with ANOVA for significance (usually time consuming because I need to check each variable's effect separately)

This all looks ridiculous and unconnected to me. Are all these methods do the same? All the forums I read showcased only one of the tools but never compared to the other. Can anyone tell me where I get things wrong and, what are the steps needed to be taken in order to do feature selection on a linear model?

Comment: What is the sample size, and how many parameters do you have to estimate?

Comment: I have 100 samples, 9 continues variables and a factor which has 5 levels, which, I'll need to break to 5 separate dummy variables + create interactions (have no idea how to decide which)

Comment: Do you need to include interactions of the factor with all continuous variables or just with a single one?

Comment: I don't know, and I have no tool to figure out the best combinations apart from putting them by hand and comparing in ANOVA with a simple model - which is, of course, unpractical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to many people I understood the following:

1. Unlike more sophisticated algorithms such as Trees or Random Forest, Linear Regression doesn't have much "auto selected" functions, thus I either need to get domain knowledge in the field I write the model for or to use `step()`, which so far, is the only auto-selection function I know about.
2. T-test is being shown in the `summary()` and is useful when I want to see if adding an **individual** variable is a good idea.
3. `anova()`, also called the partial F-test, is useful when I want to see if adding **several** variables together make the model better.

Answer (score 1):

If you do univariate variable selection and use p-values to guide your decision then your overall significance level is not same as in individual case. At least sort of Bonferroni correction is in order.

But I recommend comparing two models:

1) Full model with all variables included
2) Restricted one

F-test can be used in this case

http://www.ucl.ac.uk/~uctp41a/b203/lecture8.pdf

Comment: Agree. This is the most basic approach. However, in practive, I have 9 continues variables and another factor with 5 levels. I won't compare by hand the Full model with each variation or the Reduced model :/

Comment: Forward or backward stepwise regression variable selection method could also be used.